# How to get NIST Time from Matlab using tcp connection?

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, time

I want to get the actual date and time from Nist.gov servers in MatLab using tcp connection to their server "time.nist.gov".

I've already tried another method using url https://nist.time.gov/actualtime.cgi?lzbc=siqm9b but it doesn't work anymore as it says "Use of this script is explicitly forbidden".

I coded this, but the return variable is a "uint8" 1x51 array and I cannot get what I need:

```
clc;
Nist_Time = tcpclient('time.nist.gov',13);
pause(0.5);
tcpdata = read(Nist_Time);
disp(tcpdata)
```

I expect to get a string with the 'tcpclient' formula where I can convert it into "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
Nist_Time = tcpclient('time.nist.gov',13);
pause(0.5);
tcpdata = read(Nist_Time);
str = char(tcpdata);
str = str(8:15);
```